# "Ghost Nodes" in System.Windows.Forms.TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-3.5

I have a simple form with a `TreeView` called treeView1 and I like to add some nodes to it in the `HandleCreated` handler like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;

            treeView1.HandleCreated += delegate
            {
                // Add one and only one node
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("A Node"));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When running this form there are actually two nodes visible! When I click the checkbox on the second node, the first node is checked/unchecked.

Does anybody know a way to prevent this "ghost node"?

The reason why I want to add nodes in the `HandleCreated` is, that this handler is used in a thread function which actually constructs a data structure for the nodes to be added. Adding the nodes later would mean I have to re-write a lot of my code.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird! Looks like a bug to me... You should report it to the [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) site.

One solution if you really want to hook on the handle creation is to derive from TreeView, like this, and use this class instead of the standard TreeView:

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("A Node"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Unfortunately I cannot derive from the TreeView (it comes from another source). I decided to switch to VisibleChanged instead and make sure to work on the nodes only the first time this event occurs. Seems like HandleCreated is a precarious moment to manipulate the control. I did as you suggested and made a report on the connect site. I will post here what the MS guys have to say.

Comment: Actually MS has [nothing to say](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/667057/ghost-nodes-in-system-windows-forms-treeview#details)